# Remove older docker images but not layers that are still referenced

Tags: docker

Say I have a build machine which builds many docker images `myimage:myversion`. I consume about 1GB disk space per 100 images created and I certainly don't need all of them. I'd like to keep, say, the most recent 10 images (and delete everything older) but I want to make sure I have all of the cached layers from the 10 builds/image. If I have all of the layers cached, then I'm more likely to have a fast build on my next run.

The problem is all of the images (very old and brand new) share a lot of layers so I can't blindly delete the old ones as there is a ton of overlap with the new ones.

I don't want to use `docker image prune` (https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-images) as that depends on which containers I have (regardless of state) and am deleting the containers so prune will end up deleting way too much stuff.

Is there a simple command I can run periodically to achieve the state I described above?

Answer (score 5):

Simple, no, but some shell wizardry is possible.  I think this shell script will do what you want:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
docker images --filter 'reference=myimage:*' \
              --format '{{ .CreatedAt }}/{{ .ID }}/{{ .Repository }}:{{ .Tag }}' \
  | sort -r \
  | tail +11 \
  | cut -d / -f 2 \
  | xargs docker rmi
```

(You might try running this one step at a time to see what comes out.)

In smaller pieces:

1. List all of the `myimage:*` images in a format that starts with their date.  (If you're using a private registry you must include the registry name as a separate part and you must explicitly include the tag; for instance to list all of your GCR images you need `-f 'reference=gcr.io/*/*:*'`.)
2. Sort them, by the date, newest first.
3. Skip the first 10 lines and start printing at the 11th.
4. Take only the second slash-separated field (which from the `--format` option is the hex image ID).
5. Convert that to command-line arguments to `docker rmi`.

The [extended `docker images` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output) lists all of the valid `--format` options.

Comment: I was doing (almost) exactly this but was worried about 1) deleting common shared layers e.g. ubuntu or - scenario 2 - if Docker complains about not deleting images due to a shared layer (again like ubuntu or some installed package) then it won't delete any of the layers at all. Say every image just has two layers: the first is shared among all images and the second of which is unique to every image, how do I delete the second layer for all the older images?

Comment: You can delete old images that share common layers with newer images. Docker will only delete a layer after the last reference to that layer is gone. If all of the layers are still being used, you'll see that docker only deletes the tag.

Comment: Also you can `--filter=reference=...` for just specific image names you're interested in.

Comment: alternative for cut, you can use: `cut -d '/' -f 2` the above did not work for me